# Issue with mocha tests with should.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, should.js

I have the following code (mocha test with `should.js`):

```
it('must not be valid with empty object', function (done) {
  var result = {};
  result.should.not.be.object;
});
```

It passes, although result is an `object`. It also with passes `result.should.be.object`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/tj/should.js#object-number-array-boolean-function-string-error), you probably need to capitalize `object` on that line.

Comment: Why does it pass with `object`?

Comment: 5 second brainstorm: Since using `object` without capitalizing it doesn't actually test anything (it returns undefined, leaving the should-wrapped object with no actual test happening), there's nothing telling Mocha to fail this test, so it'll pass by default. Or some such thing.